# PSI and index do not match: PSI and index do not match on Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, psi

Whenever I clean my project is says: PSI and index do not match
What should I do?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

**Important note: This will wipe the shelf, local history, and potentially other cached data.**

File menu > Invalidate caches and restart. The PSI cache is one of the caches that are affected by this command, so this should fix it up.

Comment: Warning: This deletes shelved changes

Comment: Is there way to wipe PSI cache only?

Comment: After restart you might see `Indexing...` + gradle build actions that could take some minutes.

Comment: "Open recent" history is preserved

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I navigated to a class, I'd get this PSI error. Clicking the details in Android Studio, it included the following:

`viewProvider=SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=jar://<user-directory>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.haha/haha/2.0.3/e0672395ac43377f2510b14839342a24fdf35c18/haha-2.0.3-sources.jar!/com/squareup/haha/guava/io/GwtWorkarounds.java, content=VirtualFileContent{size=5678}}`

Based on this info, I tried deleting `<user-directory>/.gradle/caches/modules-2` and restarting Android Studio and it seemed to fix the PSI error, and it didn't seem to delete local history (though I don't know if anything else important was deleted).

Comment: deleting the `modules-2` folder worked for me. Note: it requires that Android Studio is closed. (I use Android Studio 2.3.3 currently)

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating caches didn't work for me.
Only a complete re-install of AS and all relevant SDK, Gradle etc... did the trick.
I started by uninstalling AS.
Then I manually deleted the SDK folder.
I also deleted the .gradle and .android folders in my C:/Users/[my.user]/ folder.

Comment: Such a brutal method! :) Have you tried, for instance, to create a project in a new folder? As to me, new folder didn't work. But File > Invalidate caches / Restart... did.

Comment: Brutal indeed, i don't actually like it very much, but nothing else worked for me. New project did work. Invalidating cache didnt work. Even re-installing AS didn't work. I had to wipe every last trace, i wouldn't have gone to the extreme if the mild had worked. Surely there is a more elegant solution, I just didn't have that kind of time.